# Renaming HTML classes across CSS files

Tags: html, css, rename, renaming

If I have 100 HTML files that use a set of classes that are used as selectors in CSS files, is there a utility that I can use to intelligently rename the classes?

I know that every editor/IDE has a find/replace in project feature.  Using sed you can do the same thing.  This is not intelligent because it is a simple string replace.  I want to know of a tool that actually understands what a CSS class is and how to replace instances of it.  I suppose a fancy regular expression can do the same thing.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question with several solutions?

Comment: Huh? What is a class other than a string inside an element tag in the form `class="whatever"`? The only 'fancy' thing I can think of is using a regular expression to look for tags and replacing an instance of `class="whatever"` inside each tags. I think you're making this process way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Do you mean an HTML class or a CSS selector? There is no such thing as a "CSS class", but the term is commonly mistakenly applied to both of the above.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I am referring to HTML classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Google's [Closure stylesheets](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/#Renaming).
One of the closure stylesheets features is [renaming](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/#Renaming).

example of closure stylesheets renaming features as following.

```
<style>
  .descriptive-parent-class-name .descriptive-element-class-name {color:red;}
</style>
<div class="descriptive-parent-class-name">
  <p class="descriptive-element-class-name">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p class="descriptive-element-class-name">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

would become

```
<style>
  .a-b .a-c {color:red;}
</style>
<div class="a-b">
  <p class="a-c">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p class="a-c">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

There'll be further minification features too.

Also check [closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

if you inspect any Google/Facebook page, you'll see their class and ID names are almost never longer than 4 random characters

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Netbeans 6.9 m1. It has **CSS Refactoring / Find Usages Support** maybe that is what are you looking for.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthy69m1#CSS_Refactoring_.2F_Find_Usages_Support

Answer (score 0):

If this is still up-to-date there is a library called `rcs` short for `rename-css-selectors`.

This is the library and it is pretty easy to use: [rcs-core](https://github.com/JPeer264/node-rcs-core)

It comes with a lot of plugins, such as webpack, parcel and node: https://github.com/JPeer264/node-rcs-core#plugins